# How do I get only the attributes as in HTML the page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes

Let's assume a HTML like this (attributes aren't fixed):

```
<input type='text' value='a' name='A' id='A'> <br>
<input type='text' value='b' id='B'><br>
<input type='checkbox' name='C'><br>
```

I'd like to get only the attributes as seen in the HTML, i.e from first `input`: `type`, `value`, `name`, and `id`. From second, `text`, `value` and `id`. And so on. Not all attributes of a DOM element like `.attributes` property does return.

Imaginary code:

```
function grab_attributes(element)
{
  var result = {};
  var attributes = element.attributes;
  for(var key in attributes)
  {
    if(is_seen_in_html_page(key))
      result[key] = attributes[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

So (considering above HTML as our `document`)

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("*") [0];
var result = grab_attributes(e);
```

Result is:

```
{type: "text", value: "a", name: "A", id: "A"}
```

I'm stuck on how to define the `is_seen_in_html_page(e)` function. I'm looking for an elegant solution as possible, without regex to get that values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are attribute nodes, so they are instances of `Attr`.

```
function grab_attributes(element) {
  var result = {};
  var attributes = element.attributes;
  var attribute;
  for(var key in attributes) {      
    attribute = attributes[key];
    if (attribute instanceof Attr) {
      result[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: It's a lot cleaner than my version and does not require any heavy parsing! +1

Comment: This! the `instanceof Attr` was exactly what I was looking for. I've tried `typeof x` to see if I get a different type to exclude the ones I'm not looking for but it returned `string` for all.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the element's HTML and parse it this way:

```
function grab_attributes(el){
    var result = {},
      tag = el.outerHTML, // <input type=...>
      attr = tag.substring( tag.indexOf(' ')+1, tag.indexOf('>') ).split(' '), // ['type="text"',...]
      result = {};
    for(var i = 0, l = attr.length; i<l; i++){
        var item = attr[i].split('='); // [name,value]
        result[ item[0] ] = item[1].substring(1, item[1].length-1);
    }
    return result; // {type: "text", value: "a", name: "A", id: "A"}
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Note that this method may be improved. It will only work if attributes are separated by a single space, and if there is no '/' at the end of the opening tag. Values also need to be wrapped inside quotes.

**Anyway, [ThW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2265374/thw)'s answer is way better**.

Comment: The problem with regexp is that it's easy to broke the entire algorithm. If one of the attribute's value has a `=` like `a = 1` or a white space it will return wrong results. It does handle attributes without quotes too (I know this last one is easy to work around but it isn't the point).

Comment: @Jack You're right, anyway, I gave it a try, but [ThW](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2265374/thw)'s answer is what you are looking for :)